# Input event suggestionItemSelected not fire

Tags: sapui5

I have a Input component:

```
<Input
   value=""
   showSuggestion="true"
   showValueHelp="true"
   valueHelpOnly="true"
   valueHelpRequest="handleValueLocalHelp"
   suggestionItemSelected="onLiveChangeSimple"
/>
```

and this is my function:

```
onLiveChangeSimple: function (oEvent) {
        console.log("OK!")
    },
```

When I clik on the input I show the suggestion items in a Help Diaolog; then I select one item and the Input value change correctly **but `onLiveChangeSimple` don't fire**! Why?

If I modify the input in this mode:

```
<Input
       value=""
       liveChange="onLiveChangeSimple"
    />
```

`onLiveChangeSimple` start...

What is the event fired when I clik on an Item in a Help dialog?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is where I insert the item options. I not use suggestionItems aggregation but SelectDialog https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.SelectDialog/samples

Comment: ...as is outlined in the API (see also my comment on 03/12 below)

Answer (score 0):

It should fire just fine... but I noticed you haven't specified an aggregation `suggestionItems` in your `Input` control, are you managing things in a different way?

```
<Input
  id="productInput"
  type="Text"
  placeholder="Enter Name ..."
  showSuggestion="true"
  suggestionItems="{/}"
  suggestionItemSelected="suggestionItemSelected">
    <suggestionItems>
      <core:Item text="{name}" />
    </suggestionItems>
</Input>
```

See the below working example of how the `suggestionItemSelected` event is fired:

```js
jQuery.sap.require("sap.m.MessageBox");

sap.ui.controller("view1.initial", {
  onInit : function(oEvent) {
    var aData = [
      {name: "Dente, Al", userid: "/c01/b2/u3/u44"},
      {name: "Friese, Andy", userid: "/a01ss/a2/u3/u44"},
      {name: "Mann, Anita", userid: "/U013333/u2/u3/u44"},
      {name: "Schutt, Doris", userid: "/U01/u2/u3/u44"},
      {name: "Open, Doris", userid: "/U01/u2/u3/u44"},
      {name: "Dewit, Kenya", userid: "/U01/u2/u3/u44"},
      {name: "Zar, Lou", userid: "/U01/bu2/u3/u44"},
      {name: "Burr, Tim", userid: "U08"},
      {name: "Hughes, Tish", userid: "U09"},
      {name: "Town, Mo", userid: "U10"},
      {name: "Case, Justin", userid: "U11"},
      {name: "Time, Justin", userid: "U12"},
      {name: "Barr, Sandy", userid: "U13"},
      {name: "Poole, Gene", userid: "U14"},
      {name: "Ander, Corey", userid: "U15"},
      {name: "Early, Brighton", userid: "U16"},
      {name: "Noring, Constance", userid: "U17"},
      {name: "O'Lantern, Jack", userid: "U18"},
      {name: "Tress, Matt", userid: "U19"},
      {name: "Turner, Paige", userid: "U20"}
    ];

    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    oModel.setData(aData);
    this.getView().setModel(oModel);
  },

  suggestionItemSelected: function(oEvent) {
    sap.m.MessageBox.show("Selected " + oEvent.getParameter("selectedItem").getBindingContext().getObject().name);
  }
});

var oView = sap.ui.xmlview({
  viewContent: jQuery("#view1").html()
});

oView.placeAt("uiArea");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>

    <title>SAPUI5 template</title>

    <style>
        .sapUiUfdShellBackground, .sapMGlobalBackgroundColor {
            background-color: transparent !important;
            background-image: none !important;
        }

        .sapMShellGlobalInnerBackground {
            background-image: none !important;
        }
    </style>
    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
        src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
        data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
        data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
        data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"></script>

    <script id="view1" type="ui5/xmlview">
        <mvc:View
          height="100%"
          controllerName="view1.initial"
          xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
          xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
          xmlns="sap.m">
            <Input
              id="productInput"
              type="Text"
              placeholder="Enter Name ..."
              showSuggestion="true"
              suggestionItems="{/}"
              suggestionItemSelected="suggestionItemSelected">
                <suggestionItems>
                  <core:Item text="{name}" />
                </suggestionItems>
            </Input>
        </mvc:View>
    </script>

</head>

<body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
    <div id="uiArea"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I think that the problem is where I insert the item options. I not use `suggestionItems` aggregation but `SelectDialog`  https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.SelectDialog/samples

Comment: Well, there you have it... the [API specifically states](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Input.html#event:suggestionItemSelected) : `This event is only fired when showSuggestion is set to true **and there are suggestionItems shown** in the suggestion popup`